# Bug/Error from Blaze Query

Tags: python, blaze

I am trying to use the python module blaze. when i use it on small datasets it works. when i move to larger, more complex datasets i am getting errors. I include an example below. Given the error, it seems that blaze is having trouble turning the first column into a date. How do I specify the dtype of a specific column as string so Blaze doesn't try to parse. Thanks.

```
In [2]:
from pandas import *
from pylab import *
import pandas as pd
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import csv
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib
%matplotlib inline
import timeit
import blaze as bz
from blaze import *
bz.__version__
Out[2]:
'0.6.5'

In [3]:
t = Table('C:/Users/CRSP 1991 Current.csv')

In [4]:
t.columns
Out[4]:
[u'PERMNO',
 u'date',
 u'SICCD',
 u'PERMCO',
 u'PRC',
 u'RET',
 u'SHROUT',
 u'vwretd',
 u'ewretd']

In [5]:
t
C:\Users\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py:239: FormatterWarning: Exception in text/html formatter: Unable to parse "12/31/1991" as a date
  FormatterWarning,
Out[5]:
<repr(<blaze.api.table.Table at 0x186bd3c8>) failed: ValueError: Unable to parse "12/31/1991" as a date>

In [6]:
t_smaller = t.PERMNO
t_smaller
Out[6]:
PERMNO
0   10001
1   10001
2   10001
3   10001
4   10001
5   10001
6   10001
7   10001
8   10001
9   10001
10  10001

In [7]:
t_smaller_10001 = t_smaller[t_smaller == 10001]
t_smaller_10001

Out[7]:
<repr(<blaze.expr.table.Column at 0x18819048>) failed: ValueError: Unable to parse "12/31/1991" as a date>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is handled in more recent versions.  Try updating Blaze via conda

```
conda install blaze -c blaze
```

The main anaconda channel is updated relatively infrequently.  The blaze channel (this is the `-c blaze` part) is updated on a weekly basis.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. good tip either way to get the most recent version. but i am just getting a new, related error. happy to try anything but not really sure where to start on this one. maybe just download date in different format?

Comment: ValueError: Automatic datashape discovery failed
Discovered the following datashape: 
 { PERMNO : ?int64, date : ?date, SICCD : ?int64, PERMCO : ?int64, PRC : float64, RET : float64, SHROUT : ?int64, vwretd : float64, ewretd : float64 }
But DyND generated the following error: 
 Unable to parse "12/31/1991" as a date
Consider providing type hints using typehints={'column-name': 'type'}
like typehints={'start-time': 'string'}

Comment: Yeah, DyND (what we currently use to parse datetimes), sees "12/31/1991" as ambiguous (it's not sure if it's MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY (although in this case that seems obvious)).  Current work will actually correct this behavior as a side effect.  Check back in in a couple days.

Comment: Great, this makes sense. Is there a 'best' date format in python/pandas/balze in your opinion?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 Is a pretty broadly accepted standard across languages.

Comment: How to solve this error?                                                                          Exception in thread "Rules agent factory thread for com.blazesoft.server.local.NdLocalServiceAgentDispenser@21408926" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fico/decmethod/dag/DAG
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fico/decmethod/dag/DAG